# What's wrong with this code? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I'm learning how to program on codeacademy.com and I've asked there for help already but I get no right answer.
The exercise is to build a "rock, paper, scissors" game (6. What if choice1 is rock?) And this is my code:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
    if (choice1 === choice2) {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    } else if (choice1 === "rock") {
        if (choice2 === "scissors") {
            return "rock wins";
        } else {
            return "paper wins";
        }
    };
```

It always says "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".
The answer I got was: "as @name mentioned you need to close the function as well or in this case the else if before the function."

But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try to write your code chunk by chunk, and check if it is still valid after **EVERY SMALL CHANGE**. That way you would be able to tell what exact change has broken it. Writing a wall of broken code at once then guessing why it's wrong is not what would lead you to any success any time soon.

Comment: You're missing an `}` at the end; look at the indentation and notice you are not 'back' to the leftmost level on the last line.

Comment: Further to what the others said, if you count the opening `{` brackets in your code you'll find there are 5, but only 4 closing `}` brackets. So you need to figure out where the missing `}` should go.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing brace for your `else if` statement, eg should be:

```
var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {

    if (choice1 === choice2) {

        return "The result is a tie!";
    }

    else if (choice1 === "rock") {

        if(choice2 === "scissors") {

            return "rock wins";
        }
        else {

            return "paper wins";
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As **mikeyq6** aswered, you are missing a closing brace. You can use http://jshint.com/ to check your syntax. I recommend to use jshint everytime you get something wrong in your syntax.